# Cannot populate input from Axios after Call API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

render form to input values:

```
return (
```

handleSubmit will check if the form is valid and ready to be submit, it call the callback function
                  // that is in our case, the onSubmit()

```
    The name property specifies what piece of state is being edited
                  <Field
                      label="Email"
                      type="email"
                      name="Email"
                      component={this.renderField}
                  />

            <Field name="city" 
                label="Cidade"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}                                  
                component="select">               
                        </Field>

                  <Field
                      label="Password"
                      type="password"
                      name="password"
                      component={this.renderField}
                  />
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  <Link to="/register" className="btn btn-danger">Already registered?</Link>
              </form>
          );
```

I'm getting the values from json but the field it's empty

Comment: Doing res.data gets an array of city elements

Comment: Now the question is, what is `options`.

Comment: Maybe you need to render selectbox as soon as this.state.cities is populated.

Comment: @lumio options it's the let options variable, i want to pass the values to the inputs of select options, can you guide me please?

Comment: Add your full render function

Comment: I updated the question now @lumio

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial state might not be set, so `this.state.cities` is actually empty.

Do something like this in your render function:

```
render() {
  const options = ( this.state.cities || [] ).map( (city) => ( {
      value: city.name,
      label: city.id
  } );

  return (
    -- other components --

    { options.length ? (
        <Field name="city"
            label="Cidade"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            component="select"
        />
      ) : null }

    -- other components --
  );
}
```

`( this.state.cities || [] )` will check if `this.state.cities` is available, otherwise it uses an empty array.

---

A little more detail: Your axios call is asynchronous. That means, that React doesn't wait for axios to fetch your data but instead just tries to render something.

Your state has not been set (probably) and therefore you get this error.

Comment: Thanks it's now working, the problem it's that the select options dont show in the form. Can you please help? @lumio

Comment: Is your console.log working `GetCitys().then`? Please update your question then

Comment: It's getting all data from json but don't get the values in the select input @lumio

Comment: It is null until it has been loaded. React rerenders your component as soon as your state changes.

Comment: Not working the field render for select @lumio, after wait for the answer the render dont show the values.

Comment: Does it work with static data? Can you post your full component?

Comment: I'm using redux-forms it could be because of that?? @lumio